# How to describe a certain nested object in Context api typescript?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to describe this structure inside of interface for the context api default state any idea how to describe this structure in the right way ?
the following description is not working. its and object that has objects inside a the later object the key is an id and the value is an array of 2 values id and item both ids are different .

```js
groups: {id : string ; [id: string, item: string]};
```

```js
const defaultState: appContext = {
  groups: {},
};
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

not sure the objective here but maybe this is what you want?

```
interface Item { id: string, item: string; }

interface Groups { id: string; items: Array<Item> }
```